# Getting Google Analytic Entrance Sources using Gattica Ruby Gem

Tags: ruby, google-analytics, rubygems

I am trying to get the entrance source from Google Analytic by using Gattica Gem, but I couldn't find any document on the internet. Have anyone met with this issue before? Please give me light. Thank you all so much.

Comment: Did you try googling for Gattica and RDoc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this as my solution. Thank you all

```
results = @analytic.get({
            :start_date => '2009-01-01',
            :end_date => date[:end_date],
            :dimensions => ['year', "source"],
            :metrics => ['visits']
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this, link It might solve most of your queries

https://github.com/chrisle/gattica